# Laravel Eloquent Where not working after joining table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have written a little query which doesnt seem to working when I use Eloquent but works when I write something similar in MySQL. Data isnt being retuned which shouldnt be due to my where clauses.

I have written this query which isnt working as expected -

```
$invoices = Invoice::leftJoin('user_details', 'invoices.user_id', 'user_details.user_id')
    ->where('invoices.practice_id', '!=', 'user_details.practice_id')
    ->first();
```

It is returning data where the `invoice.practice_id` = `user_details.practice_id`

I altered the query to prove it isnt working -

```
$invoices = Invoice::select('invoices.practice_id', 'user_details.practice_id')
    ->leftJoin('user_details', 'invoices.user_id', 'user_details.user_id')
    ->where('invoices.practice_id', '!=', 'user_details.practice_id')
    ->first();
```

The values returned the practice_id is `6, 6` which shouldnt be possible due to the following where clause `where('invoices.practice_id', '!=', 'user_details.practice_id')`

Have I done something wrong which I am just not seeing?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

**UPDATE**

Here is the DB schema for the invoice table
[image]

Here is the the DB schema fro the user_details table
[image]

The expected result is mentioned above, no results should be returned if `invoice_practice_id = user_details.practice_id`

Comment: Describe  DB schema here with sample data and explain your expected result.

Comment: @MohammedShafeek I have just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

@Luke Rayner

Try by rewriting `line ->leftJoin('user_details', 'invoices.user_id', 'user_details.user_id')`

to

```
->leftJoin('user_details', 'invoices.user_id', '=', 'user_details.user_id')
```

If not try to print [Last query](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-get-last-executed-query-in-larave-5example.html) and post it

Comment: I just tried and the same issues is happening I'm afraid

Comment: If it is nothing obvious it must be something else I have done wrong which i will try and figure it. I wanted to post the question in case it was something silly I did